# Intermittent SQL Server connectivity issues in production

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, connectivity

I am running an ASP.NET based application, running on two load-balanced web servers, that communicate with a SQL Server 2008 R2 database running on a separate server on the same network in the datacenter. Each application pool runs under its own service account, which are set up in Active Directory, which runs on another separate server on the same network in the datacenter.

SQL Server is configured to use Windows authentication, and 99% of the time, everything works just fine. However, from time to time, we get the following `SqlException` thrown on our webservers:

> The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows
>   authentication

Usually an app pool recycle will fix the issue, but this is not good for continuous site availability.

Switching to SQL authentication is not an option; is there anything I can be trying to ensure that this error doesn't occur?

Comment: I would take a guess this is an issue with your domain controller, especially if you have multiple that handle authentication. Need to find out when that error occurs which controller is handling authentication for the server that host SQL Server. Could also be DNS to but something with the domain.

Comment: We have a local domain controller in the data centre which is replicated from the master domain controller back on-premise. I suspect that traffic from the data center to the on-premise DC is firewalled so that the web/database servers cannot access it, but only the local DC.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the clock on each of the servers involved, including the primary domain controller. This can happen when the time on a server is not correct.

Comment: @DavidKeaveny - did you get a resolution to this problem?  I know it's a while ago now ;-)